# How to use python to select sql server from multiple places into tuple

Tags: python, sql

I have a connected server and I want to select multiple attributes that are not FROM the same place and then append them to their respective tuple.

My code does not allow selecting from multiple places and when I try to make 3 different selections and then append it isn't getting what I want.

My code:

```
cursor = conn.execute("SELECT Number, Name, Phone, Blanket, Keys from Person, Items, necessity")

for row in cursor:
    list.append(row)
```

Comment: Could you please specify the schema of the tables you are working with, as well as an example what the result should look like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please, the schema & desired output would help a great deal. Without that I can only guess that you need something like this:

cursor = conn.execute("SELECT p.Number, p.Name, p.Phone, i.Blanket, n.Keys 
                        FROM Person as p, Items as i, necessity as n
                        JOIN[some join conditions or where statements here]")

The problem may be that the fields you are asking for exist in each table so the SQL server does not know which to fetch. Also the join statements I refer to define how the rows in each table are tied to one another. The SQL server has no way to automatically figure this out unless every table is already in perfect order and has no overlapping data, which may be the case for a simple example.

Also what SQL server are you using?